# How to map a custom URL to a REST resource in an SPA?

Tags: javascript, rest, single-page-application

I have a design issue with my SPA, and hope someone can give me some direction. A user profile page is rendered like this:

1. The browser fetches `/some-username`.
2. The server checks to see if the request was a XMLHTTPRequest or not. It is not, and so it simply returns the bundled javascript app to the browser to execute.
3. The javascript bundle is executed in the browser, it sees the current URL and makes an AJAX request, again to `/some-username`.
4. The server sees the XMLHTTPRequest header, looks up the user who has the custom URL "/some-username" and returns the JSON data about the user back to the javascript to render.

This feels wrong. The app should be making RESTful requests to `/users/:id` to fetch the user data. But how can it know the id that corresponds to the user with the URL `/some-username`?

It is worth adding an extra HTTP request just to look up the resource identifier? Something like `/get_user_id?url=/some-username`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason the request should go to `/users/:id`?

Comment: I am trying to design a RESTful API. Fetching a resource from a custom URL is not the right way.

Comment: @1in7billion We are talking about 2 different URLs here one describes the state of the SPA REST client and the other identifies a REST resource. If you don't see that, then you obviously don't have the skills necessary to design anything "RESTful". You probably won't need it anyways, because your app won't have 3rd party clients, so that's okay.

Comment: I do see that, and I am trying to work out how the app should know which resource to request based on it's current state. All it has to go on is the URL loaded in the browser (and also it knows it is looking for a user).

Answer (score 1):

Are you flexible about your API? If so you may change `/some-username` to `/user-id` or if you want to include username `/user-id/username` but ignore username.

As alternative it is also common to make requests in a filter form. Like `/users?username=peter`

And feel free to use `/users/peter` if your username identifies the user. Becuase it's actualy the id (that doesn't have to be integer) and then your url is exactly `/users/:id`

Comment: The URLs must remain custom. Like Twitter, for example.

Your second point is interesting. The app could fetch the user resource via `/users?url=/some-username`.

Comment: why do you want to mention url instead of username?

Comment: The javascript does not know the username. It loads, initializes, and the router sees that the current URL is `/some-username`. It has no data about the user yet. I should mention that the user is also able to change their own custom URL, so we can't assume their username === 'some-username'.

Comment: As for your third point, the server is expecting an integer (user id). If I change it to expect a username it will break other parts of my app.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "unRESTful" about `/some-username`. It's just another resource. The response - I hope - contains the canonical URL `/user/id` anyway, either as a header or as some kind of "self" link.

That's also how you could achieve your goal. Embed the URL in the page either as JavaScript or as a header equivalent (unfortunately you cannot read the headers of the page request with JavaScript):

```
//header. Can also use a custom header like X-User-Location 
<meta http-eqiv="Location" content="/user/id">

//JavaScript
<script>
var userURL = '/user/id
</script>
```

I recommend keeping your current approach.